# How can i calculate runrate from the list containing dictionaries?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I'm trying to calculate Net run rate for the list containing dictionaries.
Suppose the list is:

```
score = [{'dismissal': 'run out (Hardik Pandya)', 'balls': '92', 'name': 'Amla', 'fours': '5', 'six': '0', 'runs': '71'}, 
{'dismissal': 'c Kohli    b Bumrah', 'balls': '32', 'name': 'Markram(c)', 'fours': '4', 'six': '1', 'runs': '32'}, 
{'dismissal': 'c Rohit    b Hardik Pandya', 'balls': '5', 'name': 'Duminy', 'fours': '0', 'six': '0', 'runs': '1'}
..........]
```

I'm trying to calculate NRR for these values which are dynamic they keep changing, I tried using enumerate but I can't figure out how to proceed further.

```
  dic= {k+str(i): v for i, x in enumerate(score, 1) for k, v in x.items()}
```

This will add indexes to the key of a dictionary. How can I proceed after this? Is there any other way it's possible to achieve this?
By the way, to calculate NRR formula is = (runs/balls)*100, any assistance will be helpful.

Expecting to get something like this:

```
dic = [{'dismissal1': 'run out (Hardik Pandya)', 'balls1': '92', 'name1': 'Amla', 'fours1': '5', 'six1': '0', 'runs1': '71','NRR1':'19.3'}, 
{'dismissal2': 'c Kohli    b Bumrah', 'balls2': '32', 'name2': 'Markram(c)', 'fours2': '4', 'six2': '1', 'runs2': '32','NRR2':'44.3'}, 
{'dismissal3': 'c Rohit    b Hardik Pandya', 'balls3': '5', 'name3': 'Duminy', 'fours3': '0', 'six3': '0', 'runs3': '1','NRR3':'45.3'}
..........]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost there with the one liner for updating the dictionary. Just tweak your dict/list comprehension as follows:

```
dic= {k+str(i+1): v for i, x in enumerate(score, 1) for k, v in x.items()}
```

Since `enumerate` is 0-indexed, you might want to add a `str(i+1)`

Demo:

```
>>> score = [{'dismissal': 'run out (Hardik Pandya)', 'balls': '92', 'name': 'Amla', 'fours': '5', 'six': '0', 'runs': '71'}, {'dismissal': 'c Kohli    b Bumrah', 'balls': '32', 'name': 'Markram(c)', 'fours': '4', 'six': '1', 'runs': '32'}, {'dismissal': 'c Rohit    b Hardik Pandya', 'balls': '5', 'name': 'Duminy', 'fours': '0', 'six': '0', 'runs': '1'}]
>>> dic= [{k+str(i+1): v for k, v in x.items()} for i, x in enumerate(score)]
>>> dic
[{'balls1': '92', 'runs1': '71', 'six1': '0', 'dismissal1': 'run out (Hardik Pandya)', 'name1': 'Amla', 'fours1': '5'}, {'runs2': '32', 'balls2': '32', 'six2': '1', 'dismissal2': 'c Kohli    b Bumrah', 'name2': 'Markram(c)', 'fours2': '4'}, {'runs3': '1', 'balls3': '5', 'six3': '0', 'dismissal3': 'c Rohit    b Hardik Pandya', 'name3': 'Duminy', 'fours3': '0'}]
```

---

To Calculate the Net Runrate, it is recommended that you do not use a list comprehension - for readability. You can just use a for - loop that would compute the NRR

```
final_scores = []
for i, x in enumerate(score):
    nrr = int(x.get('runs'))/float(x.get('balls')) * 100
    x.update({'NRR': round(nrr, 2)})
    y  = {k+str(i+1): v for k, v in x.items()}
    final_scores.append(y)
```

Lets see this in action:

```
>>> final_scores = []
>>> for i, x in enumerate(score):
...     nrr = int(x.get('runs'))/float(x.get('balls')) * 100
...     x.update({'NRR': nrr})
...     y  = {k+str(i+1): v for k, v in x.items()}
...     final_scores.append(y)
... 
>>> final_scores
[{'balls1': '92', 'runs1': '71', 'six1': '0', 'dismissal1': 'run out (Hardik Pandya)', 'name1': 'Amla', 'fours1': '5', 'NRR1': 77.17}, {'runs2': '32', 'balls2': '32', 'six2': '1', 'dismissal2': 'c Kohli    b Bumrah', 'name2': 'Markram(c)', 'NRR2': 100.0, 'fours2': '4'}, {'runs3': '1', 'balls3': '5', 'six3': '0', 'dismissal3': 'c Rohit    b Hardik Pandya', 'name3': 'Duminy', 'fours3': '0', 'NRR3': 20.0}]
```

Can this be made more concise ? Probably -   but i will leave that to you.

Comment: thanks karthik, I can't think of making more concise than your answer. If I want to calculate bowlers economy based on overs, can I do as follow? economy = int(x.get('runs'))/float(x.get(('overs')*6)) * 100, no I can't do like this since over can be a fraction

Comment: bowler= [
            {
                "maidens": "0",
                "runs": "15",
                "overs": "4",
                "name": "D Willey*",
                "wickets": "2"
            },
            {
                "maidens": "0",
                "runs": "32",
                "overs": "3",
                "name": "Jhye Richardson",
                "wickets": "2"
            }
        ],

Comment: How about converting overs to number of balls, and multiplying by 6?

Answer (score 0):

This is one way:

```
lst = [{'dismissal': 'run out (Hardik Pandya)', 'balls': '92', 'name': 'Amla', 'fours': '5', 'six': '0', 'runs': '71'}, 
       {'dismissal': 'c Kohli    b Bumrah', 'balls': '32', 'name': 'Markram(c)', 'fours': '4', 'six': '1', 'runs': '32'}, 
       {'dismissal': 'c Rohit    b Hardik Pandya', 'balls': '5', 'name': 'Duminy', 'fours': '0', 'six': '0', 'runs': '1'}]

# add identifiers and convert numeric data
lst = [{k+str(i): int(v) if v.isdigit() else v \
                  for k, v in d.items()} \
                  for i, d in enumerate(lst, 1)]

# add NRR
for d in lst:
    idx = list(d.keys())[0][-1]
    d['NRR'+idx] = d['runs'+idx] / d['balls'+idx] * 100

# [{'NRR1': 77.17391304347827,
#   'balls1': 92,
#   'dismissal1': 'run out (Hardik Pandya)',
#   'fours1': 5,
#   'name1': 'Amla',
#   'runs1': 71,
#   'six1': 0},
#  {'NRR2': 100.0,
#   'balls2': 32,
#   'dismissal2': 'c Kohli    b Bumrah',
#   'fours2': 4,
#   'name2': 'Markram(c)',
#   'runs2': 32,
#   'six2': 1},
#   ...
```

Comment: @steve, sure no problem. If it helped, feel free to accept the answer (tick on left).

Answer (score 0):

One can also use dataframe approach for clear code to calculate NRR:

```
import pandas as pd
ddf = pd.DataFrame(score)               # dictionary to dataframe
ddf.balls = ddf.balls.astype(int)       # convert string to integers
ddf.runs = ddf.runs.astype(int)
ddf['NRR']= 100 * ddf.runs / ddf.balls  # calculate NRR
print(ddf)
```

Output:

```
   balls                   dismissal fours        name  runs six         NRR
0     92     run out (Hardik Pandya)     5        Amla    71   0   77.173913
1     32         c Kohli    b Bumrah     4  Markram(c)    32   1  100.000000
2      5  c Rohit    b Hardik Pandya     0      Duminy     1   0   20.000000
```

This can also be converted to dictionary:

```
newdict = ddf.to_dict(orient='records')
print(newdict)
```

Output:

```
[{'dismissal': 'run out (Hardik Pandya)', 'NRR': 77.17391304347827, 'runs': 71, 'fours': '5', 'name': 'Amla', 'balls': 92, 'six': '0'}, 
{'dismissal': 'c Kohli    b Bumrah', 'NRR': 100.0, 'runs': 32, 'fours': '4', 'name': 'Markram(c)', 'balls': 32, 'six': '1'}, 
{'dismissal': 'c Rohit    b Hardik Pandya', 'NRR': 20.0, 'runs': 1, 'fours': '0', 'name': 'Duminy', 'balls': 5, 'six': '0'}]
```

For bowler economy (as asked in comments):

```
bowler= [ { "maidens": "0", "runs": "15", "overs": "4", "name": "D Willey*", "wickets": "2" }, { "maidens": "0", "runs": "32", "overs": "3", "name": "Jhye Richardson", "wickets": "2" } ]
ddf = pd.DataFrame(bowler)
ddf['economy'] = 100* ddf.runs.astype(int) / (ddf.overs.astype(int) * 6)
print(ddf)
```

Output:

```
  maidens             name overs runs wickets     economy
0       0        D Willey*     4   15       2   62.500000
1       0  Jhye Richardson     3   32       2  177.777778
```

Comment: cool, it looks neat thanks for answer but how can I get value of keys like if it is in list i can easily get value and I can render it to  template, How can I render  value when they are in the table format, I never used data frame before, please explain me

Comment: Dataframes are extremely useful and form basis for packages like pandas and also whole language of R. See https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python_pandas/python_pandas_dataframe.htm and https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html for tutorials and google for more.

Comment: See edit in my answer above regarding bowlers' economy. By the way, runs per ball (`runs/balls`) will be more directly informative than `100* runs/balls` for both run rate and bowlers' economy.